# count function to return all numbers instead of one

Tags: python, sorting, count

I have a huge list full of numbers and I want to sort them on occurence.

I spent a long time on google and Chatgpt and found out about this count function but in all examples, this function only returns one of the numbers with its occurence.

```
sample_list = ["a", "ab", "a", "abc", "ab", "ab"]
print(sample_list.count("a"))
print(sample_list.count("ab"))
```

This will only give me the occurence from A & Ab

How do I print all numbers and there occurence?

So if I have these number (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3,) I want them to be showcased like this

```
1:3x
2:2x
3:1x
```

also in this way from most to least.

idk who closed this but that topic is in a way similair but it doesnt give me what i want.

Look this are my numbers:
28 29 31 37 50
14 28 31 47 50
09 16 27 41 45
07 14 34 41 49
06 11 16 35 44
01 12 15 31 47
09 16 17 27 31
04 09 29 34 37
20 21 30 41 43
01 07 17 44 50
10 15 25 37 46
03 10 20 36 42
01 02 06 14 45
05 12 15 21 39
13 20 34 38 43
01 05 12 18 20
06 20 27 38 49
01 18 37 46 48
04 11 12 16 42
06 17 22 39 46
09 16 32 34 48
05 18 21 29 45
08 13 16 44 47
06 21 23 26 43
06 12 36 37 44
10 11 31 37 44
01 15 19 24 33
16 28 32 36 48
05 19 33 37 42
07 11 20 21 29
16 28 31 35 42
05 13 16 41 45
12 21 24 28 40
04 08 09 30 35
11 12 13 23 26
17 18 30 33 35
06 11 29 34 39
10 27 30 32 34
28 30 31 45 46
01 05 08 20 35
01 02 11 14 36
01 03 29 45 47
02 08 16 21 39
08 09 11 13 50
05 07 21 22 29
08 13 24 35 46
11 29 32 46 47
05 19 33 36 42
09 18 30 34 48
02 03 18 23 39
07 10 13 34 47
03 14 23 41 43
19 21 23 36 39
09 18 20 40 41
11 15 17 24 46
02 04 12 31 50
14 16 24 40 43
07 16 22 38 41
03 09 11 20 39
10 16 34 36 49
02 09 38 40 44
03 17 19 32 38
06 12 25 31 37
01 35 36 38 39
12 21 23 26 41
02 16 22 28 46
08 40 41 46 47
02 05 11 27 38
14 18 20 39 42
01 13 16 23 27
09 11 13 15 25
21 29 31 46 49
05 13 43 45 50
03 08 10 31 36
08 18 26 38 39
14 24 31 44 45
23 24 38 42 44
14 24 29 45 48
13 28 29 31 47
17 18 40 43 50
07 08 12 21 43
16 23 30 37 41
06 08 42 49 50
11 16 22 34 46
05 14 35 40 47
06 13 15 20 40
06 15 21 34 48
06 21 23 31 39
26 36 43 47 49
01 17 22 29 31
09 30 34 38 48
04 14 15 20 28
09 20 21 22 38

Is there a way of doing this without having to pu , in between them and not write down all 50 numbers in the print()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> sample_list = ["a", "ab", "a", "abc", "ab", "ab"]
>>> Counter(sample_list)
Counter({'ab': 3, 'a': 2, 'abc': 1})
```

Comment: Yeah but that way i got to insert all number in the counter but i got 50 of them

Comment: @G-JGAMES this is copy-pasted with the interactive repl's `>>>` in order to show the result. You need to remove them if you're copy-pasting.

Comment: Answer would not sort by number of occurrences, As of Python 3.7, Counter gives results by insertion order so would not be sorted. A sort process is required for example `c = dict(sorted(c.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse = True))` where `c` is the return value from the Counter function.

Comment: @user19077881 or you can do `dict(c.most_common())` to get the same result.

Comment: @slothrop  Thanks, That's a better idea.; and OP result could be printed directly from the Tuples List without conversion to Dict.

Comment: Thanks all. I eventually found a great solution that did exactly what it should do. I thought i posted it here as answer but for somereason its gone.